# Cómo pasar argumentos a la función main

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 if(argv[1] == "-c"){
     printf("imprime esto");
 }
}
```

El problema está en que a pesar de que paso el parámetro al programa en la consola, como por ejemplo:

```
./Miprograma -c
```

No me imprime lo que está dentro del condicional. No he entendido al parecer cómo funciona esto.

Sin embargo cuando hago un:

```
FILE *in;
in = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
```

Y le envío, por ejemplo:

```
./Miprograma texto.txt
```

Lo toma bien.

¿Qué pasa entonces que no me funciona el condicional de arriba? Si `argv[1]` está devolviendo una cadena que debería ser `"-m"`, que es igual al del condicional.

Comment: En C no puedes comparar cadenas con `==` debes usar la función `strcmp()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen diferentes formas de tratar los parámetros de entrada de un ejecutable, pero en particular la forma que has elegido está mal porque estás comparando dos punteros entre sí.

Por un lado `argv[1]` es un puntero que apunta al comienzo de una cadena de caracteres (una secuencia de valores `char`, uno por cada carácter de la cadena, terminada por un carácter nulo `\0`) y, por otro lado, `"-c"` es también un puntero a una cadena de caracteres.

Como son dos zonas de memoria diferentes esa igualdad no se cumplirá nunca.

Tendrías que usar una función que compare las dos cadenas entre sí carácter a carácter, como [`strcmp()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0) {
    printf("imprime esto");
  }
}
```

Comment: eso pensé he intenté hacer lo siguiente: strcpy(string , argv[1]); para copiar como tal el contenido de argv[1] a una variable que cree como char *string; y después dije: if(*string == "-m") y realice la acción del bloque